# grub2win BasicArrayRead input file open error

Tags: grub, windows-11, grub2, android-x86

I am trying to make dual boot Windows 11 and Android x86 Using `Advanced Android x86 Installer`, This wizard use grub2win to boot Androidx86, but it seems that configuration files for boot is not configured properly or does not exist.

This is the warning error:

[image: Error Warning]

Dir Tree of `C:\grub2\windata\`

```
├───backups
│   ├───bcds
│   ├───logs
│   └───main
├───partdump
├───storage
└───updatedata
```

Comment: There is not enough information in your post. For example, what you have configured and how, also the contents of the erroneous `.cfg` file.

Comment: There's no custom config files for android-x86 in `./windata/customconfigs`. The installer should create .cfg automically. But when `install the latest grub2win` opt checked this error happens.